# is there a way to align two HTML elements side by side without CSS? How?

Tags: css, github, markdown

I was just updating [my profile readme](https://github.com/carlos3g/carlos3g) on Github, but i had a issue. I need to align two elements side by side vertically, but, when I tried to use CSS, I just found out that [it's impossible to use style attr on Github's Markdown files](https://github.community/t/github-flavored-markdown-doesnt-render-css-styles-inside-a-html-block/126258). So, how can I align two elements side by side, vertically, without CSS?
My code:

```html
<details>
    <summary>Minhas Estátisticas no Github</summary>
    <p align="center">
        <img src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api?locale=pt-br&username=carlos3g&theme=radical&show_icons=true&include_all_commits=true" alt="Estátisticas Gerais" />
    </p>
    <p align="center">
        <img src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs?locale=pt-br&username=carlos3g&theme=radical" alt="Techs utilizadas nos projetos" />
    </p>
</details>
```

I want align these two `p` tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `p` tags which are block element by default if want to make these two images align side by side remove `p` tags from your code

```
<details>
    <summary>Minhas Estátisticas no Github</summary>
    <p>
        <img align="left" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api?locale=pt-br&username=carlos3g&theme=radical&show_icons=true&include_all_commits=true" alt="Estátisticas Gerais" />

        <img align="right" src="https://github-readme-stats.vercel.app/api/top-langs?locale=pt-br&username=carlos3g&theme=radical" alt="Techs utilizadas nos projetos">
    </p>
</details>
```

Note: I used the `p` tag to make more space between the summary title and the details

You can also use tables if want but it's not very useful in this situation. [Here a good guide to using tables in markdown](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/working-tables-github-markdown)

Answer (score 0):

Using pipes worked for me in Jupyter, did not check with GitHub though.
You can even place images  side by side using pipes

```
| a | b | c |
| - | - | - |
```

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |

[Markdown Guide](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/)